# Azure Functions and Opentelemetry

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, open-telemetry

I am trying to get OpenTelemetry working on Azure Functions (Python).

When the library is installed and used, the functions time out at 5 minutes (`azure-monitor-opentelemetry==1.1.1`).

The functions contain `AsgiMiddleware` to handle routing, etc.

I suspect that it is linked to this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1626.

Is there something I am missing?

I want to see traces in AppInsights. Tried all open telemetry libraries. The function app just times out with 504.

```
from api.routes.main import app
import azure.functions as func
import os
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.context import attach, detach
from opentelemetry.trace.propagation.tracecontext import \
  TraceContextTextMapPropagator


app_insights_connection = os.getenv('APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING')

configure_azure_monitor(
    connection_string=app_insights_connection
)

tracer = trace.get_tracer('events')

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    functions_current_context = {
        "traceparent": context.trace_context.Traceparent,
        "tracestate": context.trace_context.Tracestate
    }
    parent_context = TraceContextTextMapPropagator().extract(
        carrier=functions_current_context
    )
    token = attach(parent_context)
    response = await func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle_async(req)
    detach(token)
    return response
```

Comment: can you share your code please? is it long running job ? by default azure function has a 5min timeout on consumption plan

Comment: @Ilan Please share your code?

Comment: The code is not long-running, it's a basic DB query with some formatting. That all runs behind asgi handler which runs fast API in the background. Here is the code for the entry into the Azure function, I have posted the code below.

Comment: @Ilan check this [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter#microsoft-opentelemetry-exporter-for-azure-monitor) to use `opentelemetry` for application Insights with correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For `Opentelemetry` reference I used [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/monitor/azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter#tracing-1) which I suggested in comment.

This worked for me.
**#Mycode:**
**`__init__.py`:**

```py
from opentelemetry import trace
import os
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorTraceExporter
from asgi_tools import App
import azure.functions as func


trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
exporter = AzureMonitorTraceExporter(
    connection_string = os.environ["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(BatchSpanProcessor(exporter))

app = App()

@app.route('/api/HttpTrigger1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
async def http_trigger_1(request):
    with trace.get_tracer(__name__).start_as_current_span("http-trigger-1-endpoint"):
        return "Hello from HttpTrigger1!"
    
azure_function_app = func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle_async

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    TracerProvider().force_flush()
    return await azure_function_app(req)
```

**`local.settings.json`:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**`requirements.txt`**

```
azure-functions
opentelemetry-api
opentelemetry-sdk
azure-monitor-opentelemetry
asgi_tools
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]